# How to instantiate an "empty" object from a class that provides only copy-constructor?

Tags: c++, boost, stl, queue, condition-variable

I implemented a thread-safe templatized queue:

```
template<class T> class queue {

private:    
    boost::mutex mutex;
    boost::condition_variable emptyCondition;
    boost::condition_variable fullCondition;

    boost::scoped_ptr< std::queue<T> > std_queue;
     ...

public:
   ...

  T pop() {
        T r; // [*]
        {
            boost::mutex::scoped_lock popLock(mutex);
            while (queueIsEmpty())
                emptyCondition.wait(popLock);

            r = std_queue->front();
            std_queue->pop();
        }

        fullCondition.notify_one();    
        return r;
    }
     ...
```

I cannot instantiate object in the way I do (where marked with `[*]`) because of the lack of constructor for `T`, without formal parameters.

So: is there a way, maybe using a pointer to `T` and the copy-constructor (that I know it is implemented for each `T`), to avoid many template specializations?

**Edit 1**

I also thought to this possible solution.

```
T pop() {
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock popLock(mutex);
    while (queueIsEmpty())
        emptyCondition.wait(popLock);

    T r(std_queue->front());
    std_queue->pop();

    // update overall number of pop
    popNo++;

    popLock.unlock();
    fullCondition.notify_one();
    return r;
}
```

Would it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option for this scenario is to use `boost::optional`:

```
T pop() {
    boost::optional<T> r;
    {
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock popLock(mutex);
        while (queueIsEmpty())
            emptyCondition.wait(popLock);

        r = std_queue->front();
        std_queue->pop();
    }

    fullCondition.notify_one();    
    return *r;  // r is guaranteed to be engaged at this point
}
```

`boost::optional` takes care at runtime of tracking whether its contained `T` has been constructed, and so whether it needs to be destroyed.  (Note that here you don't actually need the full functionality of `boost::mutex::scoped_lock; you can use`boost::lock_guard`.)

The alternative is to notice that `scoped_lock` can be released:

```
T pop() {
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock popLock(mutex);
    while (queueIsEmpty())
        emptyCondition.wait(popLock);

    T r = std_queue->front();
    std_queue->pop();
    popLock.release();

    fullCondition.notify_one();    
    return r;
}
```

The disadvantage here is that it is less clear what the scope of `popLock` is, and a code change could result in unsafe code or deadlock.

Comment: If you explain why it is the best option you got an upvote, otherwise *too much jquery*.

Answer (score 0):

If you manually unlock you can get rid of the brackets, which removes the need to precreate the T:

```
T pop() {
   boost::mutex::scoped_lock popLock(mutex);
   while (queueIsEmpty())
      emptyCondition.wait(popLock);

   T r = std_queue->front();
   std_queue->pop();
   popLock.unlock();

   fullCondition.notify_one();    
   return r;
}
```